# why Freecodecamp css tutarial giving error

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox, css-selectors

I don't understand what is happening.
I have tried all the method but still its showing that i did not defined the image height and width.
Can you guys please show me the mistake i'm making.
[Please see this image and help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PzTV.png)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the spaces from the height and width attribute

Replace width =“100px” with width=“100px”
Replace height =“100px” with height=“100px”

Comment: But why should i use attribute..i want to use the css . So is this a glitch of codecamp?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a space between = and the first "

Removing the space might be the only thing need here.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer is not accepted and closed, I assume the question is still valid.

These tests check exact values. So, space might be an issue as others said. You can check the tests if available. Compare the tests with your code. Then you will have some idea what is going wrong.

Also, why do you have the same values 3 times? Once in inline, once as attributes and once in style tag. Are you testing for the specificity or how it is?

If that's not the intent, one of those may be an issue for the tests. It boils down to comparing the tests.

Answer (score 0):

### You made a few errors.

Firstly, you want to remove all spaces in between any styling or tags. This makes markup consistent and is probably the reason that the computer doesn't understand what you are writing.

There is no linter for coding in online editors!

Secondly, you forgot to add the semicolon at the end of your second style. You also forgot to remove the space between an equals sign in the `img` class.

Also, make sure you wrote your code in the correct place. Online editors that teach you correct syntax work a bit differently: They make you type in a different spot than you are used to. If `img` is declared outside of a place where `img` is supposed to be declared, than it may return a **`None`** to the system, asking you to try again.

Lastly, make sure that you don't 100% rely on online code editors for assignments. Try to learn Python or other related languages on your own without help -- just use Documentation!